# Uncaught ReferenceError: sceditor is not defined

Tags: html, jquery, sceditor

I'm trying to get SCEditor to work in my web app. I have loaded all the scripts correctly as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDboJ.png).
My folder looks like this APP > main.py, templates, static > css, js, minified

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='minified/themes/default.min.css') }}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='minified/sceditor.min.js') }}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='minified/formats/bbcode.js') }}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='minified/formats/xhtml.js') }}"/>
```

But I get this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: sceditor is not defined" when I call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var textarea = document.getElementById('poruka_post');

        sceditor.create(textarea, {
            format: 'bbcode',
            style: 'minified/themes/content/default.min.css',
        });

    </script>
```

Needless to say, the editor is not working with or without BBcode formatting

Comment: You should use `<script type="text/javascript" src="path.to.js"></script>` instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path.to.js" / >` to include js file.

Comment: Oh, right. Thank you very much! Copy/pasting got me

Comment: Is your (code) `<script>` tag before or after the `<script src` tags?  Is it before or after the html `poruka_post` element?  Did you try putting it in a doc.ready (as tagged [jquery])?

Comment: Nevermind, your screenshot shows you loading sceditor.min.js as a stylesheet, so not just copy+paste *into the question* but in your code as well.  Did you fix that and it worked?

Comment: Now I'm getting a different error. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_sceditor' of null. @freedomn-m My script tag is before the poruka_post element

Comment: @freedomn-m That worked., I put it in my script.js and now it's 100% functional. Thank you all for replying on such a short notice

Comment: In summary: js files loaded with `link` (as a stylesheet) and the script running before the element exists.  Glad you got it fixed.